# smallest possible linux installation with apache

Tags: linux, mysql, lamp, php5

I want to setup a linux vm with apache and php and mysql support, which version of linux should I pick up.
I dont have a good bandwidth, preferably a smaller ISO of the installer is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

What about [Turnkey LAMP appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lamp)?

Comment: This is a very good one, do you think installing any popular PHP editor on this VM will be easy?

Comment: there's already vim on it, in case you want to edit source directly on the VM. If you're more comfortable with another more graphical IDE, you should probably not work directly on the VM.

Answer (score 3):

Debian base is what I have used in the past but you can also do a stripped down install of centos for example. The distribution is immaterial really. Choose one that you are comfortable with and then just do the bare minimal install. In fact, if you don't intend to be compiling anything, you wouldn't even ever need to install the kernel sources, make, gcc or any of its brethren. 
The netinstall variants can be used if you don't mind that it will simply download the basics that are needed for the install. Or you could always try freebsd. :) (No this is not a freebsd vs linux flame. please do not interpret it as such.)

Comment: Agree. Debian has a really small footprint by default but enough packages to work along with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no rep, but I would vote for Chiefbrownbottom.

Answer (score 0):

Would [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/) or [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/) be an option instead of a full VM?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a net install of Debian. You only have to download a little bit at the start and then you apt-get install what you want. This way you won't download something you don't need.

Comment: please use aptitude nowadays for that

Answer (score 0):

Use this install Image:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jeos/hardy/daily/current/hardy-jeos-i386.iso

Open Console:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.0 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

finish :)